# Configuring Seam components with seam.properties

Tags: seam, seam-gen

I'm working on a seam project which is generated by seam-gen. It runs on JBoss 5.1.0 GA. In this project I developed a seam component and a seam.properties file like follows:

```
@Name("myBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
@Startup
public class MyBean {
    private String myField;

    public String getMyField() {
        return myField;
    }

    public void setMyField(String myField) {
        this.myField = myField;
    }
}

// seam.properties file
myBean.myField = my content
```

Actually, seam must initialize the "myField" with the content from seam.properties file. But, this is not the case for me. "myField" is null at runtime. It is not initialized. Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. seam.properties file must be placed under WEB-INF/classes folder (namely in the classpath).

Comment: This is still not the recommended way of doing it

Comment: Why is it not recommended? Is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

This is not recommended to do with seam.properties file.

You have to use it in the components.xml or write that in the code.

[See here for more details](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.Final/reference/en-US/html/xml.html#xml.descriptor)

Comment: Please elaborate instead of just pointing to the documentation. I cannot find any recommandations there.

Comment: @MPi if you click on the link, the second line says: `The components.xml file is a bit more powerful than property settings`. Thats the recommendation I was pointing too.

Comment: Ah, OK. I can see it is more powerful, but that sentence is not a recommendation in my eyes, just plainly stating the fact. A properties file is much simpler to handle than an XML file, so _my_ recommendation would be to use `seam.properties` as long as it’s good enough. But, of course, it’s also a matter of taste.